# Pygame and PyOpenGL: No shapes appear on screen

Tags: python, opengl, pygame, 2d, pyopengl

I have created a complete snake game using C++ and OpenGL before, and I want to do the same using Python, pygame, and PyOpenGL. The current problem I have is that after I spawn a fruit, it does not appear on the screen. Here's the code for my main function:

```
def main():     # Main function
    # Initialize game components
    game = Game(800, 600)
    test_fruit = game.spawn_fruit(Point(100, 100))

    # Initialize pygame module
    pygame.init()
    pygame.display.set_mode(game.get_window_size(), DOUBLEBUF | OPENGL)
    pygame.display.set_caption("Python Game")

    # Define variable to control main loop
    running = True

    # Main loop
    while running:
        # event handling, gets all event from the event queue
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            # only do something if the event is of type QUIT
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                # change the value to False, to exit the main loop
                running = False

        # Modify game properties
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        game.draw_shapes()
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.time.wait(5)
```

It's possible I'm missing a pygame or pyopengl function, but I'm not sure. I've also tried changing `pygame.display.flip()` to `pygame.display.update()`, yet it gives me an error ("cannot update an OpenGL display") instead.

Here's the code for the shape I am attempting to display:

```
class Circle:
    def __init__(self, pivot: Point, radius: int, sides: int, fill: bool, color: Color):
        self.pivot = pivot
        self.radius = radius
        self.sides = sides
        self.fill = fill
        self.color = color

    # Draw the shape of the circle
    def draw(self):
        glColor3f(self.color.r, self.color.g, self.color.b)
        if self.fill:
            glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
        else:
            glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP)
        for i in range(100):
            cosine = self.radius * cos(i*2*pi/self.sides) + self.pivot.x
            sine = self.radius * sin(i*2*pi/self.sides) + self.pivot.y
            glVertex2f(cosine, sine)
        glEnd()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGL coordinates are in range [-1.0, 1.0] (Normalized Device Space). The Normalized device space is a unique cube from the left, bottom, near (-1, -1, -1) to the right, top, far (1, 1, 1).
If you want to use "window" coordinates, you must specify an [Orthographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_projection) using [`glOrtho`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glOrtho.xml):

```py
glOrtho(0, 800, 600, 0, -1, 1)
```

Choose the matrix mode with [`glMatrixMode`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glMatrixMode.xml) and load the [Identity matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix) with [`glLoadIdentity`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glLoadIdentity.xml).

Example:

```py
def main():     # Main function
    # Initialize game components
    game = Game(800, 600)
    test_fruit = game.spawn_fruit(Point(100, 100))

    # Initialize pygame module
    pygame.init()
    pygame.display.set_mode(game.get_window_size(), DOUBLEBUF | OPENGL)
    pygame.display.set_caption("Python Game")

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    glOrtho(0, 800, 600, 0, -1, 1)
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity() 

    # Define variable to control main loop
    running = True

    # [...]
```